# Validate p:calendar value to be not greater than today's date

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I am using the component  to allow the user pick the date they were born (Birth Date). I should display an error message if the user picks a day greater than today's date to prevent the age for been a negative number. My component looks like this:

```
<p:calendar id="fechaNacimiento" yearRange="c-100:c"
    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" navigator="true"
    value="#{afiliadoController.afiliado.fecha_nacimiento}"
    requiredMessage="Debe de insertar la fecha de nacimiento del Afiliado."
    showOn="button"
    readonly="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal eq 6}"
    required="#{request.getParameter('validate')}">

</p:calendar>
```

I am using PrimeFaces and OmniFaces and JSF 2.2. I was trying to validate this by using `<o:validateOrder components=""/>` but I would need two component and I only have one. What other options do I have?

Comment: Why not use a normal validator?

Comment: I am trying to avoid that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeFaces `<p:calendar>` has a `maxdate` attribute representing maximum selectable `Date`.

OmniFaces has a `#{now}` variable representing current `Date`.

Do the math.

```
<p:calendar ... maxdate="#{now}" />
```

Comment: Excellent! I didn't realize I had the maxdate in PrimeFaces! Thanks sir!